# Generar PDFs con el plugin Gravity PDF y que se envíe al correo a los 5 días

Tags: php, wordpress

Muy buenas.

Tengo los plugins Gravity Forms para formularios de WordPress y el addon Gravity PDF que genera archivos PDF en las notificaciones del formulario enviado con los datos de formulario, etc. El caso es que necesitaría programar el envío de un PDF al usuario que rellenó el formulario y que este le llegue a los 5 días (por ejemplo).

Tengo este código php generado por chatGPT para insertar en el functions.php del tema para hacer dicha función pero no tengo mucha idea de php y dudo que este código esté correcto. Si lo está creo que simplemente habría que cambiar algún string del código.

Adjunto el código en cuestión:

`

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'send_pdf_email', 10, 2 );
function send_pdf_email( $entry, $form ) {
    // Obtener el ID del formulario
    $form_id = $form['id'];
    // Comprobar si el formulario es el correcto
    if ( $form_id == 123 ) {
        // Obtener el ID de la entrada
        $entry_id = $entry['id'];
        // Generar el PDF usando GravityPDF
        $pdf = gravity_pdf( $entry_id, 'download' );
        // Obtener el correo electrónico del formulario
        $email = rgar( $entry, '2' );
        // Configurar los parámetros del correo electrónico
        $attachments = array( $pdf );
        $headers = 'From: Mi sitio web <noreply@misitio.com>' . "\r\n";
        $subject = 'Tu PDF generado';
        $message = 'Adjunto encontrarás el PDF generado.';
        // Establecer un retraso de 5 días antes de enviar el correo electrónico
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( 5 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), 'send_pdf_email_event', array( $email, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'send_pdf_email_event', 'send_pdf_email_callback' );
function send_pdf_email_callback( $email, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ) {
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

`

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y lo probaste? o tu pregunta es si alguien lo puede probar por vos?? siempre podes cambiar el timer y ver que pasa...

Comment: No podemos ayudarte con código no probado y generado por una IA, aunque solo con verlo estoy seguro que aunque tiene buenas bases no funcionara, en especial por ese if, mi recomendación, lee la documentación de gravity forms y lee la documentación de wp_mail() y wp_cron(), investiga por tu parte y cuando tengas una duda específica de código actualizas o creas una nueva pregunta, si no hay trabajo de investigación clara y un problema de código a depurar no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Perdón, no probé aún el código. Más bien si alguien me podía sugerir alguna solución o si iba bien encaminado con este código. El problema es mi escasa experiencia con PHP...